# Как на bootstrap использовать несколько слайдеров на одной странице

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

есть 2 слайдера , по отдельности работают без проблем , вместе все ломается , ситуация такая не только с этими слайдерами , любые слайдеры не работают вместе , есть возможность их вместе использовать ? как в бутстрапе это можно настроить?

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="/template/images/main slider/1.jpg" alt="First slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="/template/images/main slider/1.jpg" alt="Second slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="/template/images/main slider/1.jpg" alt="Third slide">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
```

---

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 class="text-center mb-3">Bootstrap Multi-Card Carousel</h1>
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto">
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
              <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f44242/fff" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card 1</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/418cf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card 2</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/3ed846/fff" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card 3</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
              <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/42ebf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card 4</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: id должен быть уникальным, поэтому для второго слайдера измените id, также измените для controls и indicators на соот. id

Comment: В том и проблема что id везде разные , я пробовал 2 одинаковых слайдера ставить , и менял все id , но серавно не работает, проблема в чем то другом

Comment: bootstrap 4 -  работает - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/14ufnvLq/

Answer (score 2):

Ваш пример работает:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
1:
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="/template/images/main slider/1.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="/template/images/main slider/1.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="/template/images/main slider/1.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
2:
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1 class="text-center mb-3">Bootstrap Multi-Card Carousel</h1>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto">
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f44242/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 1</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/418cf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 2</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/3ed846/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 3</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/42ebf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 4</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Возможно вы что-то лишнее прописываете в js, либо у вас одинаковые ид, либо не подключаете на странице какие-то скрипты. С тем примером, что вы показываете, догадаться сложно, но он рабочий. И в этом примере, что вы показываете ошибок нет.

Comment: Разобрался в проблеме отчасти , у второго слайдера есть стили еще , их я не указал,и получается так как у слайдеров одинаковые классы то стили смешиваются и получается непонятно что  , я дублировал классы, все заработало но единственное так это во время скрола анимация получилась непонятная, решение не могу найти, весь код загрузил на codepen , так же там есть комментарии в файле css , одна строка в нем меняет все , т.е. слайдер который работал начинает работать не правильно, а другой наоборот, правильно -> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KQvYBJ

Comment: обновите вопрос, добавьте код в вопрос

Comment: я создал новый вопрос -> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/785103/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-bootstrap

Comment: @veti4 Это конечно хорошо, что вы новый вопрос задали, но тут принято благодарить людей  плюсами, за потраченное на вас время, если вы даже не получили устраивающий вас ответ по причине не  предоставления вами полной информации.

Comment: Пожалуй вы правы , просто был погружен в разбор проблемы и как то из головы вылетело

Comment: @veti4 не забывайте, пожалуйста в следующий раз, видите,- люди не спешат вам отвечать на новый вопрос :)